# nodejs vs javascript (Two different answers)

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
var largestNumber = function (nums) {
    let comp = (a, b) => {
        a = a.split("").reverse().join("");
        b = b.split("").reverse().join("");
        return a.localeCompare(b) > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    };
    return nums.map(v => '' + v).sort(comp).reverse().join('');

};
console.log(largestNumber([3, 30, 34, 5, 9]));
```

In nodejs
output: `9534330`
In javascript
output: `9534303`
What is happening?

Comment: Node is javascript...

Comment: What versions of the corresponding JS engines are you comparing? Might be some difference in the `array.sort()` method: https://twitter.com/mathias/status/1036626116654637057

Comment: One of the engines may by default use the `numeric: true` option of `localeCompare` while the other may not...

Comment: I believe (although I'm not certain, it's a bit hard to grok) that your sort function is nondeterministic (that is, the result depends on the order in which pairs of elements are compared), in which case the result of the sort depends on however each JS engine you test it with chooses to do it.

Comment: You should be returning `return a.localeCompare(b);`. If you do so, you will get consistent outputs in both engines - which is `9534330`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments your compare function is non deterministic and the 2 engines result in different outcomes. You could try the following in both versions to see consistent results `9534330`.

```js
var largestNumber = function (nums) {
    let comp = (a, b) => {
        a = a.split("").reverse().join("");
        b = b.split("").reverse().join("");
        return a.localeCompare(b);
    };
    return nums.map(v => '' + v).sort(comp).reverse().join('');

};
console.log(largestNumber([3, 30, 34, 5, 9]));
```